# python regex end or beginning of a sentence

Tags: python, regex

I have code as below. I want to find cases where word "eve" is present

My conditions are

1. there shouldn't be any numbers or alphabets after or before "eve"
2. before 'eve' there could be a space or nothing
3. after 'eve' there could be symbols or nothing

below code finds `['eve?', 'eve ']` but fails to find the last `eve`. How should I change the code

```
import re
your_string = "eve? is a rule, but not evening and not never. eve eve"
re.findall(r'\beve[^a-zA-Z\d:]', your_string)
```

I tried below code
where i am trying to code that after 'eve' there could be either `\b` or `[^a-zA-Z\d:]`
but it didnt work

```
import re
your_string = "eve? is a rule, but not evening and not never. eve eve"
re.findall(r'\beve(\b|[^a-zA-Z\d:])', your_string)
```

Comment: what about using negative look arounds assertions `r'(?<![a-zA-Z\d])eve(?![a-zA-Z\d])'`, note that `\b` is similar to look around because it's a 0 length match

Comment: seems to work fine to me https://regex101.com/r/aqVD6w/1

Comment: @doom87er when i run my last set of the code i get output `['', '', '']` while when i run the first set of the code above, i get `['eve', 'eve', 'eve']`. Any idea why is so?

Comment: it looks like it's taking the contents of your capture group instead of the full match, change it to a non capture group `(?:...)` it'll look like this: `\beve(?:\b|[^a-zA-Z\d:])`

Comment: thanks. could you also explain what does `:` stand for in `[^a-zA-Z\d:]`?

Comment: `[^...]` is a negated character class, `:` holds no special meaning in a character classes, so it simply includes the `:` character literally in the character class.

Comment: didnt get that. could you provide me with an example?

Comment: If i try `re.findall(r'\beve(?:\b|[^:])', your_string)` it finds `eve` as well as `eve:`...so what is the purpose of :?

Comment: @doom87er please reply if possible

Comment: the expresion `(?:\b|[^:])` is a Boolean Or that matches on a word boundary OR a character that is not ':'. It's seeing the boundary between 'eve' and ':' and matching that instead.

Comment: if you want to learn more about how Regex's work, you can find some great resources here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use word boundary on each side:

```
import re
your_string = "eve? is a rule, but not evening and not never. eve eve"
print re.findall(r'\beve\b', your_string)
```

**Output:**

```
['eve', 'eve', 'eve']
```

Answer (score 0):

Conditions are redundant, but may be translared into regex, and can be used together,:

1. add `(?<![a-zA-Z\d])` before and `(?![a-zA-Z\d])` after
2. add `(?:^|(?<=\s))` before
3. add `(?:$|(?=[^a-zA-Z\d]))` after

updated with code

```
import re
your_string = "eve? is a rule, but not evening and not never. eve eve"
re.findall(r'(?<![a-zA-Z\d])(?:^|(?<=\s))eve(?![a-zA-Z\d])(?:$|(?=[^a-zA-Z\d]))', your_string)
```

Comment: you just need to insert the expression into the right place this should not be an issue anyway

Comment: SO, is not just to find code to copy paste but to understand how it's working

Comment: The negative look around are redondant with the positive ones. If `(?:^|(?<=\s))` is satisfied, of course `(?<![a-zA-Z\d])` will be also. Same for the part after.

Comment: maybe the point is that if a character is matched in previous match, the position in input string will be after this character so it could not be match in next match like the space between the two last `eve`s however as lookarounds are not consuming the input cursor position doesn't change